# Singh - Linear Algebra: if matrices A and R are row equivalent then their row spaces are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The proof given:

[image: img1]

> Therefore the row space of matrix **A** lies in the row space of matrix **R**.

I think that the conclusion of **1)** should have been the other way around: the row space of matrix $R$ **lies** in the row space of matrix A. By following the proof for **1)**, we have:

- $A$ and $R$ are row equivalent
- Row vectors of $R$ are obtained from row vectors of $A$ by elementary row operations
- Every row vector of $R$ is a linear combination of $A$ row vectors.

This means we can express every row vector of $R$ as

$$r_{1} = k_{1} a_{1} + ... k_{n} a_{m}$$

Therefore, the row space spanned by the row vectors of $R$ can be rewritten in terms of matrix $A$ row vectors, so the row space of $R$ is a subspace of the row space of $A$, $R$ lies in $A$. As for **2)**, we have that $A$ lies in $R$. In short, I think it all should've been the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text has obvious typos: in 1 you can conclude that the row space of $R$ is contained in the row space of $A$, not the converse.

---

If the matrix $R$ can be obtained from $A$ with elementary row operations, then the rows of $R$ are linear combinations of the rows of $A$.

Let's denote by $a_i$ the rows of $A$ and $r_i$ the rows of $R$, with $1\le i\le m$. The initial statement can thus be expressed by
$$
r_i\in\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\}
$$
and therefore
$$
\operatorname{span}\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m\}\subseteq
\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\}
$$
But since you can obtain $A$ from $R$ by elementary row operations, the reverse inclusion also holds.

Comment: @Nameless Yes, you're right: the text has $A$ and $R$ swapped.